# How to display an ascii line without spaces

Tags: swift, swift3, label, line, space

I am trying to get my code to print a straight line. However the closest I can get is this.

```
   LABEL.text = "---------------------"
```

As you can see this doesn't work because there is a space between each small segment of line. What keys can a press to give me a line that does not have the spaces in between.

Comment: Why does it have to be ascii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many Unicode characters for drawing lines and boxes. For this, use:

```
label.text = "───────────────"
```

That is a series of U+2500 (BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT HORIZONTAL).

Comment: What do I type to access this?

Comment: You can copy and paste the characters from my answer or use the standard  Emoji & Symbols viewer available from the Edit menu of any Mac program.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a UILabel to show an ascii line without spacing.

You have multiple options here:

1. Look for a font that has tighter spacing for "-".
2. Use an underscore ("_").
3. Don't use an ascii line, and simply draw one, or even simpler use a UIView with 0.5 for width.

Comment: Underscore Does the same thing. Has the same space.